# Jackson equivalent to @XmlSeeAlso

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson

I am writing a RESTful web service using Java and Jersey, where the service will accept either XML or JSON inputs. Jackson is used as the JSON deserializer, and integrated into the Jersey config.

One of the endpoints is a POST request to a URL, where the content can be one of several different Java classes, and there is a common base class. These classes - with XML annotations - are:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "action")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlSeeAlso({ FirstAction.class, SecondAction.class, ThirdAction.class })
public abstract class BaseAction {
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "first-action")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class FirstAction extends BaseAction implements Serializable {
}

// Likewise for SecondAction, ThirdAction
```

In my resource I can declare a method like:

```
@POST
@Path("/{id}/action")
public Response invokeAction(@PathParam("id") String id, BaseAction action) {...}
```

Then I can POST an XML fragment that looks like `<firstAction/>` and my method will be invoked with a `FirstAction` instance. So far so good.

Where I'm struggling is getting the JSON deserialization to work as seamlessly as the XML deserialization. Where the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation was critical to get the XML deserialization working properly, it seemed that the equivalent for JSON was `@JsonSubTypes`. So I annotated the classes like this:

```
// XML annotations removed for brevity, but they are present as in the previous code snippet
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "first-action", value = FirstAction.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "second-action", value = SecondAction.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "third-action", value = ThirdAction.class) })
public abstract class BaseAction {
}

@JsonRootName("first-action")
public class FirstAction extends BaseAction implements Serializable {
}

// Likewise for SecondAction, ThirdAction
```

I then feed it my test input: `{ "first-action": null }` but all I can get is:

"org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Root name 'first-action' does not match expected ('action') for type [simple type, class com.alu.openstack.domain.compute.server.actions.BaseAction]"

Unfortunately since I'm trying to be compatible with someone else's API I can't change my sample input - `{ "first-action": null }` has to work, and deliver to my method an object of class FirstAction. (The action doesn't have any fields, which is why null shouldn't be a problem - it's the type of the class that's important).

What's the correct way to have the JSON deserialization work in the same way as the XML deserialization already is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated the use of `@JsonTypeInfo` but ran into problems because I could not alter the input format. The parser absolutely had to be able to handle input `{ "first-action":null }`. This ruled out the possibility of adding an `@type` or `@class` property. Using a wrapper object may have worked, but it choked on the `null` payload.

A crucial point was that I was using the UNWRAP_ROOT_PROPERTY configuration option. Jackson was absolutely insisting on finding an `action` property and I could not get it to consider anything else. So, I had to selectively disable UNWRAP_ROOT_PROPERTY for certain domain objects, so that Jackson would be open to parsing alternatives. I modified the project's ContextResolver.getContext(...) implementation to check for a `@JsonRootName` annotation - since this only has meaning if wrapping is enabled, I used the presence of this annotation to determine whether to return an object mapper configured with root property wrapping on, or off.

At this stage, I might have been able to use `@JsonTypeInfo(include=JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, ...)`, except for the issue with the `null` payload mentioned above (this is used to indicate that the child object has no properties - if the spec I was working from had given an empty object {} instead then there would not be a problem). So to proceed I needed a custom type resolver.

I created a new class that extended `org.codehaus.jackson.map.TypeDeserializer`, with the purpose that whenever Jackson is called to deserialize a `BaseAction` instance, it will call this custom deserializer. The deserializer will be given a subtypes array, which for BaseAction maps `first-action`, `second-action`, etc. to FirstAction.class, etc. The deserializer reads the input stream for the field name, then matches the name to a class. If the next token is an object, then it finds and delegates to the appropriate deserializer for that class, or if it is null it finds the no-args constructor and invokes it to get an object.

A class that implements org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.TypeResolverBuilder is needed that can build an instance of this previous class, and then the TypeResolverBuilder is given as a `@JsonTypeResolver` annotation on the `BaseAction` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Jackson, you are looking for `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@Type` . Please see [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) for more information

Comment: @ JsonTypeInfo seems to be about augmenting the content with extra fields to contain type information. As noted in the question, I'm writing a compatible implementation of somebody else's API, so I can't change the schema, and adding fields isn't an option unfortunately. Unless I'm missing something that @ JsonTypeInfo can do - in that case can you give an example please?

Comment: Please have a look at `@JsonTypeInfo`. It is what you need. It does NOT require addition of properties in POJO; it will just include it in JSON, which is something you have control over. Also, do not try to keep XML and JSON looking as identical as possible: JSON and XML data models are different (impedance) so the natural structures for same logical content differ in natural way.

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not work the way XML does, so the solution is not identical.

What you need to use is (like the other answer said), `@JsonTypeInfo`. That only triggers inclusion and use of the type identifier. If so, then '@JsonSubTypes` will be of use in deserialization.

The reason this indicator must be used is simple: if you have more than one alternative type to deserialize to, there must be something to differentiate.

Note, too, that this does NOT have to be a property -- while most users choose "As.PROPERTY" inclusion, it is not (IMO) the best way. "WRAPPER_OBJECT" may be what you are looking for, as it adds an extra intermediate JSON property, which is somewhat similar to what XML does.