# JAX-RS Response for XML or JSON is not working

Tags: generics, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I have the following GenericRest class which I use to extend rest classes which are based on Entity classes annotated with @XmlRootElement.

```
public class GenericRest<T extends BaseEntity> {

    @Inject @Service
    GenericService<T> service;

    public GenericService<T> getService() {
        return service;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response getAll() {
        // This works for JSON but does not work for XML Requests.
        List<T> list = getService().findAll();
        // This just gives the attributes for the BaseEntity.
        //GenericEntity<List<T>> list = new GenericEntity<List<T>>(getService().findAll()) {};
        return Response.ok(list).build();
    }
}
```

The `APPLICATION_JSON` is working fine in the currently uncommented situation, but the `APPLICATION_XML` give the error:

> Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type:
>   java.util.ArrayList of media type: application/xml

The commented situation works fine for both MediaTypes, but returns just the attributes of the `BaseEntity`, not the added attributes for the extended classes. How can I get the attributes for the extended classes **and** have both MediaTypes working?

Complete repository can be found here (work in progress): https://github.com/martijnburger/multitenant

=== Update 1 ===

I changed the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on the Entities. It was on the specific entities, but needed to be on the `BaseEntity`. Further I used the `GenericList` implementation above. This gives correct `XML` responses. However, it still returns only the `BaseEntity` attributes in `JSON` repsonses. I have two followup questions:

1. How to return a `JSON` response including the attributes for the specific object that is requested?
2. I would prefer it if the `BaseEntity` does not have to be touched when adding or removing specific `Entity` classes. Because the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation every time I add a new `Entity` class, I need to update the annotation. Is there another method to implement this where I do not need to touch the `BaseEntity`?

Repository with changes can be found here: https://github.com/martijnburger/multitenant/tree/so_36291250

=== Update 2 ===

I had good hope that the `@JsonSubTypes` annotation from Jackson would solve my problem 1. However, it did not. I updated the repository with the Jackson annotations, but I cannot see any changes in the result.

=== Update 3 ===

Please ignore my Update 2. It totally works when using Jackson 2 instead of Jackson 1. Beginners mistake. :(
Which leaves me with the question: Is it possible to get this working without touching the BaseEntity every time you add an entity.

Comment: [The `GenericEntity` is needed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35039968/2587435). As far as the entities, have you tried to put the `@XmlSeeAlso` on the `BaseEntity` class, pointing to the subclasses, i.e `@XmlSeeAlso({Car.class, Customer.class})`?

Comment: Ah! Let me try that. I was under the assumption that the `@XmlSeeAlse` was needed on the extended classes. I would however prefer to not have to touch the BaseEntity every time I am adding an Entity.

Comment: Almost funny. This change works for XML requests, but if I try a JSON request it still returns only the BaseEntity attributes. Updated branch here: https://github.com/martijnburger/multitenant/tree/so_36291250

Comment: So are you saying that before adding this, the JSON produced the correct result? I'm a bit confused as you use the word _"still"_ in your comment, but in your post you are saying that the JSON produces the correct output?

Comment: It did without the GenericEntity wrapper. With the GenericEntity wrapper it produces only attributes for the BaseEntity.

Comment: I think I need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985680/jackson-equivalent-to-xmlseealso) question also to get `JSON` working. I'll try to implement it later today.

Comment: What server are you using? Different servers have different default JSON providers

Comment: WildFly 10. It uses jackson-jaxrs 1.9.13

Comment: I haven't used Wildfly since Wildfly 8, but even then, it's default JSON provider was Jackson 2. Are you sure Wildfly 10 uses Jackson 1?

Comment: Yes./wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/main gives me a module.xml with `<resource-root path="jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar"/>`

Comment: That doesn't mean it's what's being used. Look for com/fasterxml/jackson. That should be there also. Try and use a Jackson 1 annotation like @JsonProperty to get a different name. I'm pretty sure it won't work. If that's the case, try Jackson 2 annotations

Comment: I feel like such a noob. You are totally right. Sorry, first time using jackson annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using JAXB for XML, you can use Jackson, which has an XML module. For JAX-RS you would use [this artifact](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider)<sup>1</sup>

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson2.version}</version>

    <!-- you'll probably want to use the same version as
         the jackson being used on your wildfly -->

</dependency>
```

If you use this, the XML will be handle by Jackson, which doesn't have some of the same quirks that JAXB does. And all your Jackson JSON annotations will work with this also, so you only need one set of annotations, for both XML and JSON. At a lower level, the Jackson XML provider, uses [`jackson-dataformat-xml`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml), if you want any more information about it.

From what I tested, just adding the artifact to your project is enough to make it work, though I did not test on Wildfly, I just tested with RESTeasy by itself. But I imagine is should still work.

If it doesn't work out the box, the only thing I could imagine is that the JAXB provider is taking precedence over this one. You may need to exclude the `resteasy-jaxb-provider` in a jboss-structure.xml file. But like I said, I don't think this will be required. I would've tested with Wildfly, but I really didn't feel like downloading it :-)

#### Extra

The OP is using classpath scanning<sup>2</sup> to pick auto-register resources and providers, but if you are manually registering your resources and providers in your `Application` subsclass, you will also need to manually register the `JacksonXMLProvider.class` (or `JacksonJaxbXMLProvider.class`, if you want JAXB annotation support).

---

<sub>1 - The linked project shows as deprecated, but it links to the non-deprecated later version. I linked to the deprecated one, as it has some documentation in the README, though it is very little. The newer project has no documentation at all.</sub>

<sub>2 - Empty `Application` subclass annotated with `@ApplicationPath` is enough to trigger classpath scanning. Once you override either `getClasses()` or `getSingletons()` and return an non empty set, classpath scanning is disabled.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

All variables must be private in entity definition. If someone is public does return json response but not return xml response.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. In the end I came up with a seperate solution for XML and for JSON. In this solution I do not need any annotations on the Generic classes (Like `@XmlSeeAlso` and `@JsonSubTypes`). The only drawback to this solution is that you cannot return a `Response` object in the Rest class for an XML request.

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAllJSON() {
    return Response.ok(getService().findAll()).build();
}

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<T> getAllXML() {
    return getService().findAll();
}
```

If someone knows a better implementation, I'll delete this answer.